# Gradle does not run unit tests in groovy

Tags: build.gradle, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I am trying to run a unit test in groovy. The test class itself never gets called.

My build.gradle is below:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.3"
}

tasks.withType(Test) { 
  testLogging {
    exceptionFormat "full"
    events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
    showStandardStreams true
  }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
    }

    // delete old test reports
    dependsOn cleanTest

    // don't stop if tests fail
    ignoreFailures = true

    // minimize logging
    testLogging.maxGranularity = 0

    // show stdout from tests
    onOutput { 
        dest, event -> print event.message 
    }

    // show test results
    def results = []
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "${desc.className.split("\\.")[-1]}: " +
            "${desc.name}: ${result.resultType}"
    }
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
       if (desc.className) { results << result }
    }

    // show summary
    doLast {
        println "Tests: ${results.sum { it.testCount }}" +
            ", Failures: ${results.sum { it.failedTestCount }}" +
            ", Errors: ${results.sum { it.exceptions.size() }}" + 
            ", Skipped: ${results.sum { it.skippedTestCount }}" 
    }
}
```

My folder structure is as below :

```
src
   ---main
     ---groovy
       ---<groovy class>
   ---test
      ---groovy
         ---testClass.groovy
```

When I run .gradlew test then my console shows

```
Task :test
Tests: null, Failures: null, Errors: null, Skipped: null

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

The tests are null eventhough I have declared a test class in groovy.

Could someone help in executing gradle test.

Answer (score 0):

The file name and class name were different due to which it wasn't getting called. It started working once I gave it the correct name.